# How to sum columns of an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension

How do I add up all of the values of a column in a python array? Ideally I want to do this without importing any additional libraries.

```
input_val = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

output_val = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

I know I this can be done in a nested for loop, wondering if there was a better way (like a list comprehension)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`zip` and `sum` can get that done:

**Code:**

```
[sum(x) for x in zip(*input_val)]
```

`zip` takes the contents of the input list and transposes them so that each element of the contained lists is produced at the same time.  This allows the `sum` to see the first elements of each contained list, then next iteration will get the second element of each list, etc...

**Test Code:**

```
input_val = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

print([sum(x) for x in zip(*input_val)])
```

**Results:**

```
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Answer (score 12):

In case you decide to use any library, numpy easily does this:

> np.sum(input_val,axis=0)

Comment: This method is the fastest one for an array of size 15561x22417. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Numpy is generally much faster than list comprehensions.

Answer (score 5):

You may also use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) within the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
# In Python 3.x 
>>> list(map(sum, zip(*input_val)))
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
# explicitly type-cast it to list as map returns generator expression

# In Python 2.x, explicit type-casting to list is not needed as `map` returns list
>>> map(sum, zip(*input_val))
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
input_val = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

output_val = [sum([i[b] for i in input_val]) for b in range(len(input_val[0]))]

print output_val
```

Answer (score 3):

Please construct your array using the NumPy library:

```
import numpy as np
```

create the array using the array( ) function and save it in a variable:

```
 arr = np.array(([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

apply sum( ) function to the array specifying it for the columns by setting the axis parameter to zero:

```
arr.sum(axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
[sum(i) for i in zip(*input_val)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use:

```
import numpy as np
new_list = sum(map(np.array, input_val))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the most pythonic way of doing this

```
map(sum, [x for x in zip(*input_val)])
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner using list comprehensions: for each column (length of one row), make a list of all the entries in that column, and sum that list.

```
output_val = [sum([input_val[i][j] for i in range(len(input_val))]) \
                 for j in range(len(input_val[0]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. This will make `output_val` end up as `[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]` given your `input_val`:

```
input_val = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

vals_length = len(input_val[0])
output_val = [0] * vals_length # init empty output array with 0's
for i in range(vals_length): # iterate for each index in the inputs
    for vals in input_val:
        output_val[i] += vals[i] # add to the same index

print(output_val) # [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Numpy you can easily solve this issue in one line:

**1: Input**

```
input_val = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

**2: Numpy does the math for you**

```
np.sum(input_val,axis=0)
```

**3: Then finally the results**

```
array([ 3,  6,  9, 12, 15])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output_val=input_val.sum(axis=0)
```

this would make the code even simpler I guess

Comment: Running this with the above inputs throws `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sum function instead of np.sum simply.

```
input_val = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
sum(input_val)

output: array([ 3,  6,  9, 12, 15])
```